# how to use URL and go to PDF bookmark page

Tags: pdf

For example, the pdf(https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi4/raspberry-pi-4-datasheet.pdf) has many bookmark.

I'd like to go to the specific page with a URL.
The #page=10 can be used, but it is not accurate.

Is it possible to go to the bookmark page with a URL?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that any viewer will support bookmarks nor where they will open a page , since often it is the same as the page number so try but expect page 6 OR 7 depending on viewers page number interpretation.

https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi4/raspberry-pi-4-datasheet.pdf#nameddest=interfaces

However some viewers may on occasion do better if using other methods such as comment number or two commands combined such as scroll to.

The sample you nominated above does not seem to respond to named destinations as well as other pdfs can, but does at least open that ***interfaces*** page. so trying a more complex

https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi4/raspberry-pi-4-datasheet.pdf#nameddest=Electrical%20Specification

It seems not to work in my Edge that's just page 1) which is why the advice is keep PDF bookmark corners a single unique word, never write them as War and *(another)* Piece.
Pages are the most likely to work well, but not like a ToC in the frontispiece, unless you can fully control the viewers input/response.

Also beware

PDF view settings

Search result match: Open PDFs to last viewed location when you reopen files

Since by default that was on during my testing, my result was often skewed.
Edge and Safari are usually the worst for applying URL Bookmarks, if at all.

However an offline viewer such as the one I support will usually allow driving from bookmark to bookmark via a program (here using the Win11 Cmd line for proof of ability, but can be via DDE etc.)
[image]

You enquired can the internal links be used as named destinations like the TOC unfortunately the full list of destinations is as set in this list.

```
Introduction; goto:{6; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 733.890}
Features; goto:{7; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 733.890}
    Hardware; goto:{7; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 711.439}
    Interfaces; goto:{7; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 543.295}
    Software; goto:{8; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 733.890}
Mechanical Specification; goto:{8; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 553.757}
... continues below
3 extras ADDED BY ME MANUALLY
Figure 1\: Mechanical Dimensions; goto:{8; XYZ; 12; 0.000; 481.852}
Table 2\: Absolute Maximum Ratings; goto:{9; XYZ; 12; 0.000; 789.684}
Table 3\: DC Characteristics; goto:{9; XYZ; 12; 0.000; 465.650}
... continued from above
Electrical Specification; goto:{8; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 196.355}
    Power Requirements; goto:{10; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 733.890}
Peripherals; goto:{10; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 662.151}
    GPIO Interface; goto:{10; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 625.595}
        GPIO Pin Assignments; goto:{10; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 548.239}
        GPIO Alternate Functions; goto:{11; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 733.890}
        Display Parallel Interface (DPI); goto:{12; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 733.890}
        SD/SDIO Interface; goto:{12; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 663.378}
    Camera and Display Interfaces; goto:{12; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 585.863}
    USB; goto:{12; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 494.400}
    HDMI; goto:{12; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 416.487}
    Audio and Composite (TV Out); goto:{12; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 338.574}
    Temperature Range and Thermals; goto:{12; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 240.336}
Availability; goto:{13; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 733.890}
Support; goto:{13; XYZ; 12; 72.000; 671.773}
```

To convert the TOC to destinations is an editor function, rarely found, also you may see from my manual additions, I did not set the area well thus they need manual correction of those settings. Adding bookmarks for tables or figures is chiefly a GUI task.

I have listed all available bookmarks and shown the 3 extras I attempted for ToC entries whilst exporting, however they are not URL accessible until saved as outline entries, the best method using an external go to list is '#page=X #zoom=##% and #fit=something see https://pdfobject.com/pdf/pdf_open_parameters_acro8.pdf  but they are not supported/available in all viewers (so I support SumatraPDF that uses `command line -page # -zoom ### -scroll <x,y>`

Comment: Thank you. Now I can go to specific page with #nameddest=[bookmark] 
In the RaspberryPi PDF case, It has some list of figures and list of tables links. Do you know how to go to the link by URL?

I tried to get all bookmark with Python, but I cannot get the list of figures and list of tables links name.